# How to get variable out of .then

Tags: typescript, api, axios

I just want to have the data out of this:

```
{"id":"abba5","data":24.555812751177125,"timestamp":1587380298460}
```

(This is [the URL](http://dummy-sensors.azurewebsites.net/api/sensor/abba5) )

This is the code that i use for it but it just don't work and i don't know i just want to return the data (24.555812751177125).

```
export class HttpTemperature{
getTemperature(): number{
        Axios.get('http://dummy-sensors.azurewebsites.net/api/sensor/abba5').then (response =>{
            const afgerond = parseFloat(response.data.data).toFixed(0)
            return afgerond
        })
}}
```

Comment: Well, you can't simply get the variable out of the `then` that easily, because the http call is done asynchronously. The only way you could do it would be by doing a loop that blocks until you have an answer, but that would be really bad performance-wise. That's why the concept of promised exist, so that you can chain asynchronous operations.

Comment: And how you would implement that because i don't know how that works

Comment: How you'd implement such a loop? You would declare `let afgerond` before you do the `Axios.get`. Then, after the `Axios.get` (not inside the `then` inner function), you'd have a while-loop that does nothing, like this: `while(afgerond === undefined) { }` and then return `afgerond`. But please, DON'T DO THIS. Do what diouze said, and fix the rest of your code so that it works with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `return` on your request. Btw your function is asynchronous and `toFixed` function returns a `string` so it does not return a `number`, but a `Promise` which returns a `string`, aka `Promise<string>`. If you want that your function returns a `Promise<number>`, you have to remove the `toFixed(0)`

```
export class HttpTemperature{
  getTemperature(): Promise<string> {
    return Axios.get('http://dummy-sensors.azurewebsites.net/api/sensor/abba5').then (response =>{
        const afgerond = parseFloat(response.data.data).toFixed(0)
        return afgerond
    })
}}
```

You can also use async/await like this :

```
export class HttpTemperature{
  async getTemperature(): Promise<string> {
    const response = await Axios.get('http://dummy-sensors.azurewebsites.net/api/sensor/abba5')
    const afgerond = parseFloat(response.data.data).toFixed(0)
    return afgerond
}}
```

edit:

This function is asynchronous, so to get your temperature, you will have to call `await this.getTemperature()` or `this.getTemperature().then(temperature => ...`

So something like this

```
 async jsonobjecttemperatuur(){
    const httptemperature = new HttpTemperature()
    const t = await httptemperature.getTemperature()
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for looking for it, but when i try to run that i just don't work with my other code